# IF conditional statement not working while using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to execute a script under 2 conditions, If both the conditions are satisfied then only further code can be executed.

Input Data:
**Sheet1**

```
Name        Contact_number  id_number    accuracy
Eric        9786543628      AZ256hy         90
Jack        9786543628      AZ98kds         85
Tom         9784533930      AZ256hc         80
Alan        9778934593      AZ256py         70
```

**Sheet2**

```
Name        Contact_number  id_number 
Eric        9786543628      AZ256hy  
Jack        9786543628      AZ98kds   
Tom         9784533930      AZ256hc   
David       9778984893      JH657lv
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Name        Contact_number  id_number 
    Eric        9786543628      AZ256hy  
    Jack        9786543628      AZ98kds
```

Code i have been using :

```
df = pd.read_excel(open(r'input.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(open(r'input.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet2')

if df['id_number'] = df2['id_number']  and df['accuracy'] =>85:
   df['Name'][index] = df2['Name']
   df['Contact_number'][index] = df2['Contact_number']
```

But while using this condition the if statement is not working with **AND** condition. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `df1["accuracy"]`?

Comment: You're not looping over the rows in the dataframes.

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: @Barmar  -  Yes Typing error, Corrected it. How looping over the rows in the dataframes can be done ?

Comment: @MayankPorwal - Question has been updated with expected output

Comment: @Manz Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Series.isin`:

```
In [1998]: res = df1[df1.id_number.isin(df2.id_number) & df1.accuracy.ge(85)]

In [1999]: res
Out[1999]: 
   Name  Contact_number id_number  accuracy
0  Eric      9786543628   AZ256hy        90
1  Jack      9786543628   AZ98kds        85
```

**EDIT:** If you want only certain columns:

```
In [2089]: res = df1[df1.id_number.isin(df2.id_number) & df1.accuracy.ge(85)][['Name', 'Contact_number']]

In [2090]: res
Out[2090]: 
   Name  Contact_number
0  Eric      9786543628
1  Jack      9786543628
```

Comment: what would be the case if i need to extract only two columns [''Name", "Contact_number"] values after satisfying the condition

Comment: Do `res[['Name', 'Contact_number']]`

Comment: Please suggest how to get only 2 specified columns. how we can get it.

Answer (score 3):

Edit:
I made changes to the conditions. This should work

```
df = pd.read_excel(open(r'input.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(open(r'input.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet2')

df.loc[(df['id_number'] == df2['id_number']) & (df['accuracy']>= 85),['Name','Contact_number', 'id_number']]
```

Comment: I suspect this is a copying error, since that wouldn't work without the `and` condition and they'd get a syntax error in either case.

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to compare two `series`.